# HTML: Where is the "shared" folder?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to learn some Javascript so I used the view source function in Chrome to view the HTML source of the page I am looking at. There is some reference to script files such as

```
<script src="shared/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I wonder where is this "shared" folder that stored jquery.js file? I tried to follow it as a link but it took me to

```
http://localhost:8100/shared/jquery.js
```

which is not helpful in locating the file? Where on my hard drive is this file exactly?

Comment: It's not on your hard drive. It's part of the website... If the website _is_ `http://localhost:8100` then you, as the server administrator, know what local directory that maps to.

Comment: It depends on where your webroot is.

Comment: Perhaps you need to learn basic HTML first. As comments above, assuming you took the code from www.cnn.com for example, you are looking for www.cnn.com/shared

Comment: You understand localhost means my computer? So clearly it's not on ccn. I am just testing an HTML page on my computer. But I can't find where the thing is stored? How do I find the webroot? I am running Windows XP using the Shiny package in R.

Answer (score 1):

The src attribute specify the path to the external resource file.

The path can be relative or absolute.

If the path starts with http:// or https:// it's absolute, all you need to do is just follow the path directly.

If the path starts with / , it's also absolute but you'll need to append it with the protocol and domain

If the path does not starts with http:// or https:// or / , it's called a relative path.

In most situation, it's relative based on the current web page's URL.

For for example, if the page you are browsing is http://example.com/something.html
The js is located at http://example.com/shared/jquery.js

But if you are browsing http://example.com/abc/something.html
The js is at http://example.com/abc/shared/jquery.js

There are exception though, e.g. if `<base>` tag is used to change the starting point of the "relative" path